# making an accordion toggle that works with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, mysqli

how can  i  make a simple accordian  toggle like in https://www.wireshark.org/download.html that works like getting data from a database i have,which  has questions and answers? that works simply for all the rows.
this is the current code i have and want to modify.

```
<?php
$connection = ($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] = mysqli_connect('localhost',  'root',  '')); 
((bool)mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "USE " . 'db'));

$query = "SELECT * FROM AS_Questions"; 
$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $query);
if (!$result) {
   printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}

echo "<table>"; 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   
echo "<div class='span3 tiny'>
            <div class='pricing-table-header-tiny'>
                <h2>" . $row['Question'] . "</h2>


            </div>
                <a href='##' id='s'>Show answer</a>
                <div class='dq'>
                    <div class='pricing-table-features'>
                        <p>" . $row['Answer'] . "</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class='Dass'>
                        <p id='Dassp'>Answered by:" . $row['Doctor'] . "<p>
                    </div>
                </div>

    </div>";  //$row['index'] index here is a field name
}

echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

((is_null($___mysqli_res = mysqli_close($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]))) ? false : $___mysqli_res); 
?>
```

Comment: You added a lot of tags but not the one you need: javascript.

Comment: This is not that complexe, the only thing you need to keep in mind is that if your accordion uses id's, you should increment a counter in order to give your accordions part a single and unique id.

Comment: @devpro shared  the code

Comment: @Daan sorry :D javascript addedd

Comment: @Zeratops my current code has a button that is already in  the  second  div of answer field. i  wish to  move it to the question field and right float. i tried to move the link  but code stops working after that.

Comment: this is best one... try it: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp

Comment: @devpro it only works for the first row i  pass :/

Comment: your row must have unique id...

Comment: @devpro do you mean  auto increment unique ids?

Comment: basic one: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible_panel&stacked=h

Comment: try it, i have use it with #collapse1, #collapse2, #collapse3 its working..